# Excel Formula returns error

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I am trying to use this formula but it returns me an error like this:

> The formula you typed contains an error.
>
> - To get assistance in entering a function, click OK, then click    Function on the Insert menu.
> - If you are not trying to enter a formula, avoid using an equal sign    (=) or minus sign (-), or precede it with a single quotation mark (').

What I try to use is:

```
 =IF(B2<>"",COUNTA($B$2:B2),"")
```

I am wondering why is this happening.

Edit: I use Office Mac 365

Comment: Do you use `;` instead of `,` as the delimiter?

Comment: That helped thanks. My mistake!

Answer (score 0):

The same has been answered by Scott Craner Through Comment ans which was accepted by question owner. Posting the answer behalf of him to remove from unanswered Questions.

**Do you use `;` instead of `,` as the delimiter**